# nesting columns using grid-span vs. layout properly and background-grid

Tags: sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

ahoy all,

i have been studying the Singularity grid framework and so far i really like its simplicity and concepts/mental models.  however, like others i am still a bit confused about how to do nested grids properly in Singularity.  after looking over similar questions:

- [Still confused with nested grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377578/still-confused-with-nested-grids)
- [Subgrid with floating method and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837973/subgrid-with-floating-method-and-padding/19844806#19844806)
- [Having to re-declare global context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746401/having-to-re-declare-global-context)

i came up with the following examples to created nested grids: one using only `grid-span` and another using `layout` and `grid-span`:

- [Singularity nested columns using grid-span](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7753478)
- [Singularity nested columns using layout+grid-span](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7759585)

as you can see they achieve the same end result, though using the `layout` method *feels* better.  with that in mind, my question is 2 fold:

1. is there a "best/recommended practice" for creating nested grids with Singularity?
2. why are the  grids drawn by`background-grid` on the same elements different when using `grid-span` vs. `layout`? it seems as if the nested columns are being created differently and thus have different "inner" columns?  the background grids using `layout` seem more correct, though even there some of the elements look incorrect (e.g. the "first" element has 10 columns inside it drawn by `background-grid` while it only spans 8 columns of the parent container, and the "a" & "b" elements have 6 columns drawn inside it by `background-grid` though they only span 3 columns of the parent container).

   i apologize in advance if i am misunderstanding some simple idea of Singularity.  in fact, it is probably likely ;)

   thanks in advance for any help.

peace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layout` is for when you are nesting lots of things. You just specify your context once and then you can nest sub-elements within that nested context.

`grid-span` offers one-time context assignment. It’s for nesting an individual element.

If you need to use `background-grid` within a nested context, you should use `layout` and it should identify the correct context. `background-grid` is prone to rounding errors, especially in webkit based browsers and the guides may be slightly off.

Comment: thanks for the info.  thus, since `background-grid` uses the grid context, which is only changed by modifying `$grids` or using `layout`, it only makes sense to use it within containers.  is that a correct understanding?  thanks again for the help and for Singularity.